# How to specify build options for automatic build triggered by jgitflow release-finish?

Tags: java, xml, maven, git-flow, jgitflow-maven-plugin

When I do `mvn jgitflow:release-finish`, it triggers a project build which fails because it tries to fetch a plugin from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ and our network doesn't allow that; we need to use the organization's local maven repo.

Now I've specified the URL to this local maven in my settings.xml, and normal builds work fine because I specify the path to this settings.xml as follows: `mvn clean install -gs ~/settings.xml`

But the automatic build triggered by the `jgitflow:release-finish` goal seems to use it's own build options. I want to know how can I change these build options?

The workaround I'm using right now is to set `noReleaseBuild = true` in the jgitflow plugin configs in order to skip the build altogether, but I don't want to keep doing this.

Please let me know if there's a way to specify which settings.xml file is to be used in the build triggered by `jgitflow:release-finish`

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is weird. All I did was upgraded from Maven v3.0.3 to Maven v3.2.5 and kept my user settings.xml here: `~/.m2/settings.xml` and it worked.

All the options I want to specify for the build triggered by `jgitflow:release-finish` goal can be specified along with the goal itself as in this example:

```
mvn jgitflow:release-finish -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```